# the requested operation required elevation

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to run aspnet_regiss.exe -ir as an administrator but the following error returns:

[image]

Why does this require that? I am administrator on this machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run the command prompt as administrator.  Just right-click on Command Prompt (in your Start Menu) and select "Run as Administrator"

Comment: I cant it says: "The command prompt has been disabled by your administrator"

Comment: You need to be an Administrator on the machine.  If you're not, you will need your admin to run the command for you.

Comment: that is strange because when I look at Computer Management , local users and groups, Groups I appear to be in the Administrators group?

Comment: anyways there is no other way to run this I guess then?

Comment: That is strange.  Maybe you're a local admin but there's a group policy preventing you from running it.  Are you on a Windows 7 machine?  You could try to run it from the RUN dialog (WindowsKey+R), but I kinda doubt it will work.